# std::is_reference from std::any

Tags: c++, c++17

Im a little stuck.

Trying to check if a argument is a reference type from inside my template class

It seems to work in the function.

But inside my function wrapper its always returning true.

```
#include <vector>
#include <any>

template <class T>
T CallFunction(const std::vector<std::any>& args) {
    for (size_t i = args.size(); i > 0; i--) {
        std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::is_reference<decltype(args[i-1].type())>::value << std::endl; // always true
    }
    return T();
}

template<typename Fn> class FunctionBase;
template<typename R, typename... Args>
class FunctionBase <R(__cdecl*)(Args...)> {
public:
    FunctionBase() {}
    R operator()(Args... args) {
        return CallFunction<R>({ args ... });
    }

};

int foo(int a, int& b) {
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::is_reference<decltype(a)>::value << std::endl; // falae
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::is_reference<decltype(b)>::value << std::endl; // true
    return a + b;
}

int main() {
    int in = 10;
    foo(1, in);

    FunctionBase<decltype(&foo)> func;
    func(1, in);
}
```

Comment: That's because the return type of `std::any::type()` is always `const std::type_info&`, so `std::is_reference<const std::type_info&>::value` is gonna be `true` all the time. `is_reference` is a compile time type trait, whereas `type_info` contains information about a data type during execution.

Comment: @JorgeBellon oh right. you know any other way to pass the args to the function and loop them?

Comment: If you want to check if a type inside `std::any` matches `T`, you need to call [`std::any_cast<T>(args[i-1])`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any/any_cast).

Comment: i dont want to see if it matches T, i need to be able to have any amount of arguments that are from any passed function, and then i need to be able to check if that argument is a ref

Comment: Then you might need to use `std::reference_wrapper<T>`. I'm not very familiar with `std::any`, but I don't think it can hold references, just like you can't declare `std::vector<T&>`. Then you can check if it is a reference by calling `std::any_cast<std::reference_wrapper<T>>(arg)` and `std::any_cast<T>(arg)` and see if the pointer is not null. Are you sure you really want to use `std::any` at all?

Comment: Please update your question to reflect what you want to achieve (basically what you said in your last comment).

Comment: `std::any` is very limited in what it can do. Consider using `std::variant` if possible.

Comment: when i try `std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<std::any>> vec = { args... };` i get errors cannot convert from 'initializer list'

Answer (score 2):

The premise here is incorrect. `std::any` *always* owns its own value. It moves/copies whatever you give it into local storage, and then is completely responsible for that independent entity:

```
int i = 1;
std::any a = i; // a owns an int whose value is 1, even though i is an lvalue here

i = 2;
assert(std::any_cast<int>(a) == 1); // still 1
```

The only way to store a "reference" in `std::any` is to store a type that itself behaves like a reference... like `std::reference_wrapper`:

```
int i = 1;
std::any a = std::ref(i); 

i = 2;
assert(std::any_cast<std::reference_wrapper<int>>(a).get() == 2);
```

But that's still not actually a reference, and note that you cannot get it back out with `any_cast<int>` - only `any_cast<reference_wrapper<int>>`.